# Pausing Large number of AJAX calls, multiple data sets

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chained, pause

I am trying to create a web utility that take several large datasets and makes ajax calls to process them and index them into a table for searching. Basically, the data will be broken down into 5 data sets, but for the sake of simplicity, I will reduce the sample data to two sets (basically multi-dimensional arrays).

- Inventory Items
- Systems

---

Let's just say, again for the sake of simplicity, that each dataset has 3 items in it.

**JAVASCRIPT PART 1**

```
var inventory = [
  {"id": "1","title": "0002\/840","type": "inventory"}, 
  {"id": "2","title": "0002\/841","type": "inventory"}, 
  {"id": "3","title": "0002\/842","type": "inventory"}
];
var systems = [
  {"id": "28","title": "System 1","type": "system"}, 
  {"id": "54","title": "System 2","type": "system"}, 
  {"id": "76","title": "System 3","type": "system"}
];
```

---

The way it should work is that the code hits the first inventory item, makes an ajax call based on it, waits for the response , and then moves to the second item. It does this over and over again until it reaches the last item, at which point, it moves on to the next data set (systems), and then works its way through those.

Now, I have this working just fine. You can see a fully functional example at the CodePen link below. This version of the JS code has a small delay built in to better demonstrate the issue.

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwKeZZ)**

---

It has now been requested that I add a pause/unpause function. I'm at a little bit of a loss as to how to stop this without freezing the browser, and more so, how to resume where I left off at the correct place in the correct dataset.

I tried adding a `paused` boolean variable that is toggled on and off, and then a loop in my function that would just wait for the `paused` variable to be `false`. This obviously tied up the browser window.

Can anyone shed some light on how I might be able to go about doing pausing and unpausing without freaking out the browser?

Thanks in advance.

---

**REMAINING JAVASCRIPT PART 2**

```js
var paused = false;

function PauseIndexing() {
  //paused = true;
}

function BeginIndexing() {
  updateItems(inventory, 'inventory', 0, function () {
    //This gets called when inventory is done
    updateItems(systems, 'systems', 0, function () { 
      alert("Inventory and Systems Imported");
    });
  });
}

function updateItems(items, type, x, callback) {

  /* This causes complete freeze as expected*/
  //while (paused) {}

  var item_count = items.length;

  $.post('', {
    item: items[x],
    type: type
  }, function () {
    x++;
    if (x == item_count) {
      callback();
    } else {
      updateItems(items, type, x, callback);
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: why in earth are you flooding your server with ajax request when you can send a single ajax request? for a load slider?

Comment: @madalinivascu because the process that gets run by the ajax call(s) actually freeze up my server until it is done. I prefer to call one, stop and allow other processes to complete, then call the next. This is not a public piece of code and used only by our staff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have to maintain the state of progress using `pausedAt = x`, then continue from where you left. Below is the changed snippets & the working example link.

```
function BeginIndexing(x) {
   updateItems(inventory, 'inventory', x, function () {
     pausedAt = x = 0;
    updateItems(systems, 'systems', x, function () {
      alert("Inventory and Systems Imported");
    });
  });
}
function ContinueIndexing(){
  paused = false;
  console.log(pausedAt)
  BeginIndexing(pausedAt);
} 
function updateItems(items, type, x, callback) {
if(paused){
  pausedAt = x;
  return
}
```

[Working Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyLQXX?editors=001)

or else check the result below

```js
var paused = false;
var pausedAt = 0;
var inventory = [
  {"id": "1","title": "0002\/840","type": "inventory"}, 
  {"id": "2","title": "0002\/841","type": "inventory"}, 
  {"id": "3","title": "0002\/842","type": "inventory"}, 
  {"id": "2","title": "0002\/841","type": "inventory"}, 
  {"id": "3","title": "0002\/842","type": "inventory"}, 
  {"id": "2","title": "0002\/841","type": "inventory"}, 
  {"id": "3","title": "0002\/842","type": "inventory"}, 
  {"id": "2","title": "0002\/841","type": "inventory"}, 
  {"id": "3","title": "0002\/842","type": "inventory"}
];
var systems = [
  {"id": "28","title": "System 1","type": "system"}, 
  {"id": "54","title": "System 2","type": "system"}, 
  {"id": "76","title": "System 3","type": "system"}
];

function PauseIndexing() {
  paused = true;
  //pausedAt = x;
}

function BeginIndexing(x) {
   updateItems(inventory, 'inventory', x, function () {
     pausedAt = x = 0;
    updateItems(systems, 'systems', x, function () {
      alert("Inventory and Systems Imported");
    });
  });
}
function ContinueIndexing(){
  paused = false;
  console.log(pausedAt)
  BeginIndexing(pausedAt);
} 
function updateItems(items, type, x, callback) {
if(paused){
  pausedAt = x;
  return
}
  /* This causes complete freeze as expected*/
  /*
  while (paused) {

  }
 */
  
  var item_count = items.length;

  setTimeout(function(){
    $.post('http://www.geonames.org/countries/', {
      item: items[x],
      type: type
    }, function () {
      x++;
      console.log(x);
      if (x == item_count) {
        updateBar(item_count, 100, type);
        updateText("<span style='color:#090;'>Done!</span>", type);
        callback();
      } else {
        var perc = Math.round((x / item_count) * 100);
        updateBar(x, perc, type);
        updateItems(items, type, x, callback);
      }

    });
  }, 500);
}

function updateText(val, type) {
  $('small.' + type + '_name').html(val);
}

function updateBar(x, perc, type) {
  $('.progress.' + type + ' .progress-bar')
    .attr('aria-valuenow', perc)
    .css('width', perc + '%')
    .html(x + ' (' + perc + '%)');
}

function isFunction(functionToCheck) {
  var getType = {};
  return functionToCheck && getType.toString.call(functionToCheck) === '[object Function]';
}
```

```css
.progress{background:#333;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn btn-lg btn-success" onclick="BeginIndexing(0);">Start!</div>

<div class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="PauseIndexing(true);">Pause</div>
<div class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" onclick="ContinueIndexing(false);">Continue</div>



<div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h2>9 Inventory Items</h2>
            <small class="inventory_name">Pending....</small>
            <div class="progress inventory">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
                0 (0.00%)
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <h2>3 Systems</h2>
            <small class="systems_name">Pending....</small>
            <div class="progress systems">
              <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
                0 (0.00%)
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: better disable the start button on loader loading

Comment: OP can do that much I guess..Also that would be OP's call, as we not aware of all requirements.. I focused on main problem..

Comment: Very nice! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
function PauseIndexing(pause) {
  paused = pause;
}

function updateItems(items, type, x, callback) {

  if (paused) {
    return setTimeout(updateItems, 100, items, type, x, callback);
  }

  var item_count = items.length;

  $.post('', {
    item: items[x],
    type: type
  }, function () {
    x++;
    if (x == item_count) {
      callback();
    } else {
      updateItems(items, type, x, callback);
    }
  });

}
```

Check it out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bEbvbJ

Comment: the progress bars are going all over the place

Comment: This is like continuous polling, which could cause performance issue.